# Rails Bootstrap styles not being applied (no errors)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I have a namespaced part of a Rails app that I'm working on. I'm trying to apply Bootstrap using the `bootstrap-sass` gem. I've followed the README directions precisely. The only difference is that I've renamed the manifest file that I require in my template from `application.css.scss` to `employers.css.scss`.

No matter what I do, the Bootstrap styles are not being applied to any elements within `<div id="page-wrapper">`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have another app with an identical layout and identical version of Bootstrap running that looks great.

Here is my `employers.css.scss manifest`

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require framework_and_overrides
 *= require bootstrap-popover
 *= require employers/sb-admin
 *= require employers-overrides
*/
```

Here is my `frameworks_and_overrides.css.scss`

```
// import the CSS framework
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Here is the HTML for the rendered page:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope">
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <link href="/assets/employers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/font-awesome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/framework_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap-popover.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/employers/sb-admin.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/employers-overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">

    <body signed-in="true">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="form-container ng-scope" ng-controller="NewPostQuestionCtrl">
                    <h2>CREATE</h2>
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="postQuestionForm" ng-submit="submit(postQuestion);" multipart="true" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.token" ng-init="postQuestion.token='+Itu5juZS/EvY0C8NNfxDJ7/ZV674RttZKS305b6FVU='" value="+Itu5juZS/EvY0C8NNfxDJ7/ZV674RttZKS305b6FVU=" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <input name="employer_id" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.employer_id" ng-init="postQuestion.employer_id='1'" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Question</label>
                            <textarea class="question-textbox ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="question" ng-model="postQuestion.question" required="">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <div class="button ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ngf-select="" ng-model="postQuestion.file" name="file" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="150KB" required="required">Select</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Publish Question</label>
                            <select class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="published" ng-model="postQuestion.published" required="">
                                <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
                                <option value="true">Publish</option>
                                <option value="false">Don't Publish</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <input class="submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Publish Post" ng-disabled="form.postQuestion.$invalid">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="column-layout cards-layout cols-3" id="scenes">
                    <div class="col">
                        <br style="clear:both">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried with to let the name application.css.scss instead of employers.css.scss?
Plus, try to make the `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";` at the top of your application.css.scss/employers..css.scss file.

Comment: That makes no difference. `Bootstrap` is definitely loading, as some elements outside the div are styled. It's just that nothing inside the div is styled.